# How to format object in GET request to Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, swagger, openapi

I have a Spring Boot application, which uses Maven codegen plugin to generate server code for some OpenAPI 3.0 yaml.files.

In the Swagger, I have a GET with a field of "additionalProperties":

```
...
documentMetadata
object
(query)

{
  "metadataKey1": "metadataValue1",
  "metadataKey2": "metadataValue2",
  "metadataKey3": "metadataValue3"
}
...
```

I see that Maven codegen generates a field with Map datatype for this:

```
  @JsonProperty("documentMetadata")
  @Valid
  private Map<String, Object> documentMetadata = null;
```

So far so good. The issue is that I cannot figure out how the GET request should look to send these values to the application. I am running using Postman.

I have tried various ways:

http://myapp/myservice?param1=A&param2=B&documentMetadata[lookupkey]=123

This one fails with illegal character. If I URL encode it, the field on serverside has null value.

http://myapp/myservice?param1=A&param2=B&documentMetadata={"partnerId":"123"}
(and also URL encoded tried)

This one gives me error that it cannot cast String to Map:
"Cannot convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.util.Map': no matching editors or conversion strategy found]"

Any ideas how the request should look like to get it to serialize properly to the Map?

Comment: You would usually put this in the request body. You forgot to post the GET method declaration though.

Comment: In this case I require a GET request... this is by intention.

Comment: Yes, you said this was a GET request. You can still send a body. Also, have a method declaration to show.

Comment: Tried in the body as well now. But no success. The method is declared like this `    @RequestMapping(value = "/archived-documents",
        produces = { "application/json" }, 
        method = RequestMethod.GET) 
` and the field like this: @ApiParam(value = "") @Valid @RequestParam(value = "documentMetadata", required = false) Map<String, Object> documentMetadata

Comment: If you put it in the body, you need to annotate the parameter with `@RequestBody` instead of `@RequestParam`. If this doesn't help, I don't know how to do this in a parameter.